# Questions deleted by the OP mark answers as deleted by their owner

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, deleted-answer

[This topic](https://superuser.com/questions/383879/vmware-player-installer-both-stopped-working) was deleted by the user who posted the question.

[image]

The answer was deleted with the topic. But the page says that the answer was deleted *by it's owner at the exact same time*, which is simply wrong:

[image]

---

Answers to migrated topics are deleted without a reason. This would probably be appropriate in this case too.

[image]

Comment: Seriously someone promote @Daniel to moderator, so he can go self-answer all these questions...

Comment: @IvoFlipse Well, other than `status-declined` I cannot do much about answering them even as moderator :-) And Sathya found it before I did anyway.

Comment: Interesting one. The answer OP deleted the answer, then undeleted it, before the question was deleted. So, when the question got deleted, there was a deletion record for the answer OP in place. Not sure we have a good solution for this, even going forward.